# Start activity in portrait but listen for changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, orientation, orientation-changes

I've done some searching but, I haven't found any answers to my question yet. Here's my problem: I have an activity that shows some information in portrait. Let's call this Activity A. When the user rotates their device to landscape orientation, a new activity starts, Activity B. Similar to Activiy A, if Activity B is rotated to portrait orientation, Activity A starts. Herein lies the problem. If a user's device is already in landscape before they first start the app, then Activity A loads in landscape (no bueno).

In Activity A, I've tried `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` as well as `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest, however, if i use any of those approaches, overriding `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` to listen for a change no longer works.

TDLR;

Is there a way to **guarantee** my app loads in portrait whilst still listening for orientation changes? If that's not possible, are there *any* other approaches or solutions available?

---

Relevant(enough) code:

**MainActivity.java** (The activity want to start in portrait, A.K.A, Activity A)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // Adding before setContView() doesn't work
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // Adding after setContView() doesn't work
    // anywhere I add sRO() in onCreate, overriding onConfiurationChange
    // won't register a change

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    showTutorial();

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_main, false);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    numberOfUnlocksPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.key_num_unlocks), MODE_PRIVATE);
    numberOfUnlocks = numberOfUnlocksPref.getInt(getString(R.string.key_num_unlocks), 0);

    IntentFilter updateUi = new IntentFilter();
    updateUi.addAction(ButtonReceiver.BROADCAST_LOCKS_RESET); // Listen for a reset
    updateUi.addAction(LockService.UPDATE_UI); // Makes sure the UI updates on device lock/unlock

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // If I don't use sRO() anywhere in the Main, this code works
        // BUT, the app can still start in landscape (no bueno)
        // If i do use sRO() this code won't work
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LockDataActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**LockDataActivity.java** (The class I want to start in landscape, this works and all is well)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_data);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    if (configuration.orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toasty.error(this, "Please rotate your device to go back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

If I add `android:orientation="portrait"` then I overriding onConfigChange doesn't work

Comment: Kindly post your code

Comment: updating post now

Comment: Ok,Alright! Will take a look

Comment: Updated code, take a look if you will

Comment: why do you want to listen to configuration changes?

Comment: In the MainActivity, I listen for a change to landscape to start the new activity, LockDataActivity.  In LockDataActivity, I listen for a change in portrait to go back to the MainActivity. If I don't listen for a config change in the Main, the LockData class doesn't start. Essentially, this is just a cosmetic issue I want to fix, as opening the app in landscape to switch to portrait then back to landscape again just to start the LockDataActivity is mildly annoying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161883/discussion-between-inzikhan-and-cameron-cuff).